# Modify the \textwidth of all subsubsections compatible with adjustbox

Tags: tables, width, adjustbox, fullwidth

I have a very simple document which is a succession of tables within subsubsections of the document.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,landscape,a4paper,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
```

This is my header and it works fine. But when I insert a table using `\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight},keepaspectratio}`, the table is indented to the left with regards to the title.

How can I temporarily modify the `\textwidth` property so it is taken into account by the `adjustbox` package ?

I have tried several solution so far (`titlesec`,`pagechng` and `fullwidth`) but to no avail.

It is worth mentioning that I do not want to only expand the table : the `keepaspectratio` property of the `adjustbox` package is crucial to me.

Thank you for your help.

Here is a reproductible example :

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,landscape,a4paper,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=2,atend]{bookmark}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}




\section{bla}
\subsection{blabla}
\subsubsection{blablabla}
\begin{center}
\begin{adjustbox}{max size={\textwidth}{\textheight},keepaspectratio} 
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr} 
\hline
b & b & b & b & bb & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & b & TOTAL &         Theta & Carry \\ 
\hline
\textbf{\cellcolor{lightgray}  BLA}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -8,629}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -27,295}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -17,019}  &  \ 2,076  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -45,148}  &  \ 695,726  &  \ 670,926  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -1,174,496}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -167,597}  &  \ 116,890  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -35,396}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -135,900}  &  \ 11,481  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -2,634}  &  \ 26,003  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -324,524}  &  \textcolor{red}{ \ -13,759}  &  \ 707  & \textbf{\cellcolor{lightgray}  \textcolor{red}{ \ -428,589}}  & \cellcolor{yellow}  \ 2,890  & \cellcolor{yellow}  \ 88,646  \\ 
\hline 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of code? Are you using `\noindent` before the box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @egreg: The `adjustbox` environment (but not the equivalent `\adjustbox` macro) uses already `\noindent`. However, maybe there is some code used before the environment which creates a paragraph.

Comment: @egreg - I modified the original question with a reproductible example. I also tried `\noindent` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sweave.sty` file says

```
\setboolean{Sweave@gin}{true}
\DeclareOption{nogin}{\setboolean{Sweave@gin}{false}}    

<...>

\ifthenelse{\boolean{Sweave@gin}}{\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}}{}%
```

So you have to say

```
\usepackage[nogin]{Sweave}
```

to avoid that setting.

It's also best to use the `noae` option, otherwise the package also loads the obsolete `ae` package. Final recommendation:

```
\usepackage[noae,nogin]{Sweave}
```

Comment: @Chapo I've added another recommendation.

Comment: `@egreg` OK thank you. I'll do that from now on.